# Which product should i download for dashboard of Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-ctools

I found a bunch of product of Pentaho, what i want is a software which can do the same thing than tableau software, should i download the Pentaho BI suite CE version ?  Should I build it myself ? 
Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pentaho BI Suite as a complete package provides you with all the products required to do data integration, reporting, dashboarding, olap cubes, etc. You will find all the necessary tools required to do a complete DWBI/Data analysis job.

Tableau as a software provides a reporting and dashboarding layer which you can use to visualize data available across various sources. You can do similar work using Pentaho also. Pentaho BI suite provides you with the below tools:

- Pentaho BI Platform *(User Console,Enterprise console,etc)*:  It includes features for managing security, running reports, displaying dashboards, report bursting, and OLAP analysis. You can create analysis, interactive reports and dashboards using the user console.
- Pentaho Mondrian: Supports MDX and developing cubes.
- Pentaho Report Designer: You can create reports based on the data across various sources.
- Pentaho Data Integration: ETL tool for working with data.

Pentaho also comes with two variants:

- EE (Enterprise Edition): Need to provide licensing cost. Pentaho support is available for the tool.
- CE (Community Edition) : Free of cost. No pentaho support available.

It depends on your requirement, which version you want to choose. It can be either CE or EE.

You can read more on the Pentaho Offerings in [wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaho).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the information! I have tested Pentaho BI EE, and it seems that it can do almost the same thing than Tableau software, that's a good news, but regarding to Pentaho BI CE, i had feeling that it couldn't create the same report than the EE version, I had only Jpivot view.

Comment: And I tried to find a plug-in in the marketplace, there were no much options, I installed Saiku analysis but it require licence too, so does that mean that I can not build report/dashboard without a charge with Pentaho BA CE? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try the **CTools** by Pentaho !!! Check this link : http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/ And ofcourse EE is better and more intuitive than CE version, but yes you can build dashboards/reports without charge with pentaho ce. give a look at ctools, you can build CDE dashboards and reports using PRD.

Comment: thanks for the information, I found some CTools for creation of report, but I couldn't find out how can I embed pentaho dashboard into a web page considering that they are only be exported to PDF or Excel